# I registered a service in eureka which is resolving through java code. But it is not able to resolve its name when hitting through chrome or postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, networking, dns, netflix-eureka

I have created a microservice named as USER-SERVICE and registered it in Eureka Server locally. When I  am trying to access its other modules through java-springboot code, it is accessible and the service name is resolving to my local IP. But when I am hitting the main service URL through chrome or postman. I am unable to do so.

When it was hitting when I hit the localhost URL of the service, but when I replaced the localhost and port name with the service name it is not able to resolve on windows. But same thing is able to resolve through the springboot code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.